# Reactive input working, but getting error?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I'm getting a strange error with reactivity of a select input affecting the options of another. (It's working like I intended, but I'm getting an error)

Here's the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(R.utils)

# Populate test data:
if (!exists('.foo')) .foo <- new.env()
if (!exists('.ohlc')) .ohlc <- new.env()

.foo$abc <- NA
.foo$xyz <- NA
.ohlc$abc.daily <- NA
.ohlc$abc.hourly <- NA
.ohlc$xyz.hourly <- NA
.ohlc$xyz.minute <- NA

runApp(list(
  ui = bootstrapPage(
    uiOutput("foo"),
    uiOutput("ohlc")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {

    output$foo <- renderUI({selectInput("foo", "Which foo?", ls(.foo), selected = ls(.foo)[1])})

    availPeriods <- reactive({
      inputFoo <- input$foo
      sapply(X = ls(.ohlc)[grepl(inputFoo, ls(.ohlc))], FUN = function(x) {return(capitalize(strsplit(x, "[.]")[[1]][2]))}, USE.NAMES = F)
    })

    output$ohlc <- renderUI({
      selectInput("ohlc", "OHLC Interval", availPeriods())})
  }
))
```

Here's the error message:

```
Error in grepl(inputFoo, ls(.ohlc)) : invalid 'pattern' argument
```

What I don't understand is: why am I getting this error?

The app runs and behaves like it should; the "OHLC Interval" is correctly returning the periods that are available for the given input: abc (daily & hourly), xyz (hourly & minute)

Where did I mess up? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Add this after setting `inputFoo`:  `if (is.null(inputFoo)) return()`

Comment: That works! But, can I bother to ask why? `inputFoo` is never null, so why is the check needed?

Comment: The first time it runs its NULL.  A print statement: `print(inputFoo)` will show this.

Comment: I thought that wouldn't be the case because I had `selected = ls(.foo)[1]` in the `selectInput`, but I guess that's not so. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `req` as in `inputFoo <- req(input$foo)`. This way Shiny will stop the execution of the reactive expression unless `input$foo` is truthy.

```
availPeriods <- reactive({
      inputFoo <- req(input$foo)
      sapply(X = ls(.ohlc)[grepl(inputFoo, ls(.ohlc))], FUN = function(x) {return(capitalize(strsplit(x, "[.]")[[1]][2]))}, USE.NAMES = F)
    })
```

An alternative is putting `if (is.null(inputFoo)) return()` at the top of the reactive expression, as suggested by @G.Grothendieck.